# two search variables in api pipe typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, mapquest

I'm sure I'm doing something stupid here, but I can't get figure out how to pass 2 variables using the approach that I'm using, which utilizes some rxjs. I have 2 search variables for a navigation app, from and to, which are entered into boxes searchFrom and searchTo in my html, but I can't figure out how to work it. either searchTerms needs to be an array somehow or ... something.

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  mapResult: any;
  to: any;
  from: any;

  private searchFrom: Subject<string>;
  private searchTo: Subject<string>;

  constructor(private mapQuestService: MapQuestService) {  }

  search(to: string): void {
    this.searchTo.next(to); }

  search(from: string): void {
      this.searchFrom.next(from); }



  ngOnInit() {

this.from = 'boston';
this.to = 'poughkeepsie';

this.searchTerms = new Subject<string>();
this.searchTerms.pipe(

    debounceTime(1000),

    distinctUntilChanged(),
    switchMap((to, from) => {
      return this.mapQuestService.getMap(this.to, this.from);

  ))
  .subscribe((result: any) => {

    this.mapResult = result.items;
  });
}
```

}

any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using [combineLatest](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/combinelatest.html) instead of another subject:

```js
this.searchTerms = combineLatest(this.to, this.from);
this.searchTerms.pipe(
  debounceTime(1000),
  distinctUntilChanged(),
  switchMap((to, from) => this.mapQuestService.getMap(to, from))
)
.subscribe((result: any) => this.mapResult = result.items);
```

[Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-observer-and-observable?file=app%2Fform-field-overview-example.html)
[two observables](https://stackblitz.com/edit/two-inputs-rxjs-combinelatest)

Comment: That's cool, although (noob question) 
Right now I am getting my 2 inputs from html boxes
  <form >
         <input #searchFrom id="from-box"
            (keyup)="search(searchFrom.value)"/>

            <input #searchTo id="to-box"
            (keyup)="search(searchTo.value)"/>
  </form>

so question is, how do I set searchTerms in that?

Comment: @AndrewSteier what do you mean by set? if you mean get your input to call next on the subjects, I'll update my answer with that.

Comment: So the problem I'm having is, using your method or using a modified version of mine, I'm not able to successfully pass my two input boxes into the function. so you're using searchTerms, but while I currently have this.to and this.from hardcoded, they aren't getting my search box input.

Comment: @AndrewSteier I've created a live working example for you on stackblitz, please see update on post.

Comment: So... Yes, thank you for going to the trouble. What I still don't grasp, and maybe it's just a matter of explanation, is how to modify that to take 2 distinct inputs.. my getMap takes two distinct arguments from two different search boxes. If it was just the one term, I think I could pull it off.

Comment: @AndrewSteier please 'another demo'